# Website is fine until hosted

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I have a website that I am trying to build and have built everything up. I viewed everything locally on my computer then bought a name and found a company to host it. The result is very different to my original vision. Everything seems quite blurry, things that where small before are now bigger and things have moved around.

I wonder if there is anything that I should be putting in my code to make it different? I tested it locally and hosted on chrome.

www.chloebox.com

here's the website, if anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I zoomed in 150% and everything seems fine like that.

Chrome remembers your zoom settings per domain, is it possible you developed using 150% zoom, and the live site is at 100%?

**EDIT:**
As an aside, I think your site is really hard to navigate. If I have to wait for a box to turn to be able to click on something I want to, I'll close your site really fast... The menu on the bottom is barely noticable. I would also add the static text menu to all the subpages for easier navigation. Sorry, this is not really relevant to the question, I just thought I'd add my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked like a charm! and I really appreciate your advice :) thank you.

I had wanted to make a cube that could be rotated by the user but that proved very difficult for me so i settled with this. I will definitely work on the menus, that's a great idea, thanks :D

Comment: Just to clarify, it only looks fine for you now, everyone who visits your site will have to zoom in manually to get it to display correctly. You'll want to redo your CSS on 100% zoom (press Ctrl+Numpad 0 to reset zoom to original).